# installing GNU octave for use in python oct2py

Tags: python, octave, oct2py

I am trying to install GNU octave for use in python oct2py. I have been using octave 3.6.4 alone for several months without problems but I cannot call functions octave scripts from python. While in python:

```
 import oct2py
```

I get the error message:

```
 Please install GNU Octave and put it in your path
```

my path has the following additions to the system variables:

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;;C:\Python27\;C:\Octave-3.6.4\mysys
```

I am wondering if 'GNU Octave' is different to the version of octave that I have installed? Or if there is something additional that I am not doing?

After changing the path to bin the following error ocurs in the python shell:

```
 >>> oc = oct2py.Oct2Py()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    oc = oct2py.Oct2Py()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oct2py-1.3.0-py2.7.egg\oct2py\session.py", line 67, in __init__
    self.restart()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oct2py-1.3.0-py2.7.egg\oct2py\session.py", line 503, in restart
    self._session = _Session()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oct2py-1.3.0-py2.7.egg\oct2py\session.py", line 540, in __init__
    self.proc = self.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oct2py-1.3.0-py2.7.egg\oct2py\session.py", line 572, in start
    return self.start_subprocess()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oct2py-1.3.0-py2.7.egg\oct2py\session.py", line 589, in start_subprocess
    raise Oct2PyError(errmsg)
Oct2PyError: Please install GNU Octave and put it in your path
```

Comment: Are you sure the path shouldn't point to something like `C:\Octave-3.6.4\bin` instead? Can you invoke octave by just typing `octave` in a new terminal window?

Comment: ok I have altered the path to C:\Octave-3.6.4\bin and now i can import oct2py in the python shell but the following error message occurs: see my edit

Comment: Ok, it works now. after re-booting the computer the path changes seem to have worked.